# How to make Menu tab invisible if the user is not Admin

Tags: php, mysql

How to make some menu tab option is invisible if user is not Admin, eg: if `['user_level']>=5`

```
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CBS</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li class="active"><a href="home.php">DTC</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">View Proposal</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Users details</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

I want to make only home.php menu tap visible to user only. Admin can see all the menu tab.

eg screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Server side  in php you can conditionally echo the related  element.

Assuming you user auth is assigned to $userAuth  var you can eg:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CBS</a>
</div>
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

   <?php if ( $userAuth == 'Admin' ) {
        echo '<li class="active"><a href="home.php">DTC</a></li>';
      }
  ?>
    <li><a href="#">View Proposal</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Users details</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do with **2 methods:**

**1) You have to give class hidden like this:**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<?php
if ($user_level>=5) {
    $hide = "hidden";
} else {
    $hide = "";
}
?>

<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CBS</a>
</div>
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">    
    <li class="active <?=$hide?>"><a href="home.php">DTC</a></li>
    <li class="<?=$hide?>"><a href="#">View Proposal</a></li>
    <li class="<?=$hide?>"><a href="#">Users details</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

**2) if else condition:**

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CBS</a>
</div>
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <?php if ($user_level>=5) { ?>
      <li class="active"><a href="home.php">DTC</a></li>
      <?php } else { ?>
      <li class="active"><a href="home.php">DTC</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">View Proposal</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Users details</a></li>
      <?php } ?>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don't duplicate code** - it is first rule. So better is to wrote:
(i persume that ['user_level'] is some value in array(); - here I call this array $user:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CBS</a>
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<!--first of all check if you get $user values-->
        <?php if (isset($user)): ?>
<!--    display common elements for ALL USERS -->
            <li class="active"><a href="home.php">DTC</a></li>
<!--            elements only for admins - users with level greater then 5-->
            <?php if ($user['user_level'] >= 5): ?>
                <li><a href="#">View Proposal</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Users details</a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
```